XSLT Organising a list of lists
I'm trying to re-work a list of lists, moving from XML to a proprietary XML-based file format.
Essentially the input is something like
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li><ul><li>Sub item 1</li><li>Sub item 2</li></ul></li>

  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li><ul><li>Sub item 3</li><li>Sub item 4</li></ul></li>
</ul>

which obviously looks like this:

Item 1
Sub item 1Sub item 2
Item 2
Sub item 3Sub item 4

But I need the sub item lists within the same li tag as their respective header.
So, like this:

Item 1Sub item 1Sub item 2
Item 2Sub item 3Sub item 4

When I test the original input above, I can't seem to come up with an XPATH which will pick up my first sub item ul without picking up the second subitem ul.
When running that through the transform this basically creates
<ul>
  <li>Item 1
    <ul><li>Sub item 1</li><li>Sub item 2</li></ul>
    <ul><li>Sub item 3</li><li>Sub item 4</li></ul>
  </li>

  <li>Item 2
    <ul><li>Sub item 3</li><li>Sub item 4</li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>

The XPath that has got me this far is
following-sibling::li[not(normalize-space(text()))]/*[1][self::ul or self::ol]
  

normalize-space is to isolate an li which don't have text but just ul or ol inside them. I have tried multiple variants of the above, setting the index [1] just returns them all, [2] returns nothing.
I'm a bit stuck and grateful for any input or suggestions!

This seems like a grouping problem you can tackle in XSLT 2 or later (current version of XSLT is 3.0) with for-each-group group-starting-with:
  <xsl:template match="ul[.//ul]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="li" group-starting-with="li[not(ul)]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), tail(current-group())/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

Example fiddle is here.

In XSLT 1.0 you would use a key for this:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="true"/>
  
  <!-- 
    Index child lists by the identifier of their "header" list item
  -->
  <xsl:key 
    name="child-lists-by-header-li" 
    match="li/ul"
    use="generate-id(parent::li/preceding-sibling::li[not(ul)][1])"
  />

  <!-- 
    Render a list by rendering just the "header" list items; those that doesn't 
    have child lists. Those "header" list items will render their own child lists
  -->
  <xsl:template match="ul">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="li[not(ul)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- 
    Render a list by rendering its own content, and then all of its child lists
  -->
  <xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child-lists-by-header-li', generate-id(.))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


